# Should the specification of printer technology be mandatory?

Tags: discussion

There are many different printing technologies. While it might be clear to the asker that he's talking about his home 3D printing machine, that's not necessarily the case for those that try to answer the question.

I think it would help to specify the scope of questions with tags, to allow future visitors to identify what type of 3D printer it is about. Answers to a lot of questions related to general properties of the printing process like printing speed, resolution, additional manual work, support structures, etc. depend heavily on the technology that's being used.

This also prevents "Well, it depends..." type of answers that cover a lot of possibly unrelated things.

Comment: If printer tags would be mandatory, I also think slicer tags should be as well

Comment: @EricJohnson true, I guess I over-thought this, questions should generally be tagged accordingly.

Comment: @EricJohnson Differences between slicers are minor, and many questions can be answered without that knowledge (it's fairly easy to identify overextrusion/wobble/etc... without knowing about the slicer). Knowing the technology and type of material makes much greater difference.

Answer (score 4):

For questions where the technology matters, absolutely.

If you look at Stack Overflow, for example, all questions must be tagged with the language the OP is asking about. I doubt there will be many questions that are asking about all technologies at once - and if they are, that's likely to be marked as too broad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No, there will be many questions which are more general in nature, and have little to do with the actual process used to produce the part.

We should encourage tag use for process when appropriate, but I don't think making it mandatory will work in the long term.

Comment: Sorry, I implied that it should only be mandatory for those questions it is applicable to, not mandatory to all questions.

Answer (score 2):

*Mandatory* is a probably poor choice of words. Not every question is going to be about the use of specific equipment.

As with *any* Q&A site, a user should always include enough background and support information in the body of the question so it can be answered *definitively.* If the specific material or equipment is relevant, be sure to include that information in the post.

But if that information is missing, readers can use the 'comments' section to ask the author to go back and clarify the original post. Comments are meant to ask for clarification or to include other information that can somehow improve the original post (questions and answers). Keep at it; editing and constantly improving a post is what this is all about. These posts should serve as a model to the industry and serve as a source authority. But **please do not use comment to answer questions**. Comments are not well-equipped to properly vet any content. Thanks.

Comment: makes sense, as said, I was probably over-thinking this when the first questions came in and many tags didn't exist

Comment: I just noticed that you happen to be user/1 and posted [a question on meta asking how that came to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272838/who-becomes-user-1-on-a-new-site)