# Is there a way to manually add tags?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Looking at some of the meta questions ([Should the specification of printer technology be mandatory?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/should-the-specification-of-printer-technology-be-mandatory)
,[FFF/FDM vs… everything else?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/fff-fdm-vs-everything-else)
) and having asked myself the questions about proper tagging, is there way that we can add/edit tags in mass quantities?

I'd be willing to go ahead and add various slicing engines, manufacturers, models, etc. if there was a way to create tags outside of creating questions. It might also be nice to have a cleaner way to edit tag information such as an editable table (instead of pagination).

Are these options available in moderator tools, if at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at some of the meta questions (1,2) and having asked myself the questions about proper tagging, is there way that we can add/edit tags in mass quantities?

No. That's deliberate - tags are not supposed to be treated with mass operations, but individually.

> I'd be willing to go ahead and add various slicing engines, manufacturers, models, etc. if there was a way to create tags outside of creating questions. It might also be nice to have a cleaner way to edit tag information such as an editable table (instead of pagination).

Click on a tag wherever it comes up. It takes you to the tag page, from which you can click "improve tag info" to get to the tag wiki edit page. This you can edit (or suggest an edit to, if you're [under 4000 reputation for an SE site that has the Beta status](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).

> Are these options available in moderator tools, if at all?

No. Community Managers (the Stack Exchange staff) have access to some tag mass operations, and diamond moderators can *merge* tags. Regular users have no access to batch ops.